# How to access Account Record Type by name on case validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule, record-type

How can i access account record type by name while creating a validation rule on case object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the validation rule, add the field `Account.RecordType.Name` to access the record type name of the Account in your case object.
Also, for developer name, use `Account.RecordType.DeveloperName`

Comment: I doubt if we can do that, I just tried in my developer org. Refer my answer

Comment: We can do this.

Comment: Yes, I was not referring to correct option

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a formula that will  contain the `RecordType.Name`.

now use this formula field in validation rule

..

If the RecordType object is available then use RecordType.Name directly in validation rule

[image]